# Rails 3, uploadify and nginx upload module

Tags: nginx, uploadify

I wanted to know if anyone has been able to use uploadify successfully with nginx upload module and nested attributes as well? I am having a major issue where the nginx upload module parameters (fast_asset) are not getting passed to the action. Basically since I have nested forms, the id of the file input object will not be constant, and if I try to call uploadify on the class of the file input, nothing happens.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!